# Rename all files within a folder to include checksum in the file name on Unix/Mac

Tags: regex, unix

I want to rename a bunch of images to include the SHA checksum in the file name. So, for example, this

```sh
twitter-icon.png
facebook-icon.png
linkedin-icon.png
```

becomes this

```sh
twitter-icon.23rjvn28374ughf1i2je72392qdh2jf.png
facebook-icon.89394udjnx2ebh28hdb8eghddgbxn3d.png
linkedin-icon.j399hdd83gh28bdb2nedudhdn299dhj.png
```

The closest I've come is this command

```
shasum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\(\..*\)\)$/mv -v \2 \2\1\3/' | sh
```

It gives almost the desired result with one "but" - it preserves the file extension in the generated name, like so

```sh
twitter-icon.png23rjvn28374ughf1i2je72392qdh2jf.png
             ^^^
```

How can I get rid of that extension in the middle and get the clean image name before the checksum suffix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want this:

```
shasum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\)  *\(.*\)\.\(.*\)$/mv -v "\2.\3" "\2.\1.\3"/' | sh
```

Maybe do a testrun without the `| sh` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```sh
shasum * | sed -E 's/^([^ ]+) +(.*\.)([^.]*)$/mv -- "\2\3" "\2\1.\3"/' | sh
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enables the POSIX ERE syntax
- `s` - substitution command
- `^([^ ]+) +(.*\.)([^.]*)$` - finds

  - `^` - start of string
  - `([^ ]+)` - one or more chars other than space
  - `+` - one or more spaces
  - `(.*\.)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars and then a `.`
  - `([^.]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than a `.`
  - `$` - end of string
- `mv -- "\2\3" "\2\1.\3"` - replaces the match with `mv -- "`, then Group 2 and Group 3 values concatenated, `" "`, Group 2 + Group 1, `.` and Group 3 values.